# How can I reproduce the query plan and actual running time of a past query in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

There's a query that every now and then takes about 20 seconds to complete, whereas most often it takes only 2 second to complete.

If I use `EXPLAIN`, I can't reproduce a query that takes 20 second.

Is there a way I can find out why the query has taken that long in those particular instances?

Comment: Check out the auto explain module: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html

Comment: Also [`pg_stat_plans`](https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/pg_stat_plans) or `pg_stat_statements`. Enable checkpoint logging too, see if your slow queries correspond with checkpoints.